# Autocomplete with Jquery 3.2.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using jquery 3.2.1 in my project and now I have a requirement to implement autocomplete functionality. I am getting the same error again and again with `Uncaught TypeError: dollar(...).autocomplete is not a function`
If I use the lower version of jquery than many functionalities stops working. I searched for the solution but failed. Please help me with this issue. I am using a website template for my project.

Jquery

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var dollar = $.noConflict();
        dollar(function () {
            dollar("#txtDoctorLocation").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    var param = { query: $('#txtDoctorLocation').val() };
                    dollar.ajax({
                        url: "./verification.aspx/SearchDoctor",
                        data: JSON.stringify(param),
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    value: item
                                }
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            var err = eval("(" + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + ")");
                            alert(err.Message)
                            console.log("Ajax Error!");
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 1 //This is the Char length of inputTextBox  
            });
        });
    </script>

[WebMethod]
public static List<string> SearchDoctor(string query)
{
    List<string> Doc = new List<string>();

    Doc.Add("Test1");
    Doc.Add("Test1");
    Doc.Add("Test1");
    Doc.Add("Test1");
    return Doc;
}
```

Comment: Give me your code

Comment: Please show some code to help you

Comment: I updated my question with code

Comment: Are you importing autocomplete? It's from jQuery UI, not jQuery Core (so it needs to be imported separately)

Comment: I tried with jquery ui 1.9.1 same issue

Comment: @RahulLadwal the error indicates that jQuery UI library is not be loaded or not loaded before your code is executed. Please edit your post and include how jQuery and jQuery UI are being loaded.